# AJAX request return 200 OK

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have Ajax POST request. It always return 200 OK but I am not getting what I hope. I know there is a json problem but i can't solve this problem. Here's my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#formreg").submit(function(){
    if (confirm("Are You Sure Want To Save ?")){
      $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        type:"post", 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data:$( ":input" ).serialize(), 
        dataType: "json", 
        success:function(response){
          if(response.status == 1)
           { 
             alert("Save OK !");
           }
           else
           {
             alert("Fail To Save!");
           }
        },
        error: function(xhr){
                alert("An error occurred: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
<form method="post" name="formreg" action="" id="formreg">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" size="50" maxlength="50"  /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

save.php

```
<?php
  include_once("connect.php");
  $name =   $_POST['name'];
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitor(name) VALUES('$name')") or die ("Fail To Add !");
  echo '{"status":"1"}';  
?>
```

what are the wrong code so my script doesn't work, can you help me ?

Comment: You say there's a problem, but don't tell us what the problem is. If the request returns a 200 OK response then the AJAX code is fine. If the PHP code does not perform the action you expect then you need to debug that code, not the JS

Comment: _"I am not getting what I hope"_. What do you hope to get? What are you getting?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @FastSnail good spot. I'd post that as an answer, or vote to close for a typo in the code.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Hmmm don't format your own json, let `json_encode($myArray)` do the job for you little apple !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there :

```
$name =   $_POST['$name'];
```

Replace `$name` with `name` because the identifier in your form is 'name'. Since you're passing a bad variable to the query your PHP dies and returns a status of 200, but is has died *before* you echo out your JSON string, which is why the JSON is never returned.

Comment: I think that might actually be the answer @JayBlanchard single quoted `$var` is definitely an issue

Comment: It might actually be @RiggsFolly (because of a comment above) ;-)

Comment: Look at the html, it's not `name="$name"`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ah I didnt see that - Comment Vampire eh

Comment: @JayBlanchard : thank, but this is my original code : $name = $_POST['name']; on my save.php.  Can you help me how can i echo out my JSON ... give me some script to echo it

Comment: If that is your original code @aguspriyo why haven't you made the correction on your original post so we don't chase rabbits? And we're not going to "give" you anything.